# Java Serializing different objects

Tags: java, sockets, serialization

I want to make a small network game of two clients sending messages to eachother.
I'm new to sockets and serialization but I read that sending serialized objects via sockets is the way to do.

My problem is, I have multiple types of messages. One might be a simple chat message, the other one a turn (message) like a "NewObjectMessage" or "MoveObjectMessage"...

In tutorials I always read something like

```
MyClass myClass = (MyClass) objectinputstream.readObject();
```

which does a casting to the one specific class I put in the stream on the other side.

Question is: is there any way of determining what kind of message I get?
I'm looking for something like

```
stream.peekObject()
```

or something in order to see it's type.

Or is the common way to send two messages and the first one is only a declaration telling what comes next? But what happens if some packages get mixed up and the next object is not the one I was asking for?

So what is the best way to communicate between the clients in a way of e.g. moving an object and creating an object (or writing a message etc.)?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Nope. You need a **protocol**! For example, you could send a `String` first that describes the `Object` being sent? Of you could use something like [STOMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streaming_Text_Oriented_Messaging_Protocol) which has headers, into which you can place metadata...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just read the object as an Object, and use `instanceof` to see what type it is.

Or have the objects all implement a common interface with an action method and just cast to the interface and call the method.

Comment: Would work - bit messy if there are many different types of message.

Comment: Okay, so at least I might use it like an ordinary "local" object? Okay, well, at least this might work. Still, I'm not sure this is the way to do...

Comment: Well, since no one seems to know a better solution I vote for it. Thanks alot!

Comment: @BoristheSpider if there weren't different types of message it wouldn't be necessary and the question wouldn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is `object.getClass().getName();`.